# Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-annotations' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

When i want to generate a signed APK (release) using Proguard rules i got this error message :

> Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-annotations' that    satisfies the version constraints: 
>   Dependency path 'Transition:library:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
>   Constraint path 'Transition:library:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-annotations' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
>   ...

Gradle (app) :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {        
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26      
}

buildTypes {

    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-
android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation project(':library')
implementation 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.1'
implementation group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.54'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android'
// glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
implementation ('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}}
```

Gradle (Project):

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle (Library):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26



defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Proguard rules :

```
-keep class com.jcraft.jsch.jce.*
-keep class * extends com.jcraft.jsch.KeyExchange
-keep class com.jcraft.jsch.**
-keep class com.jcraft.jzlib.**
-keep class com.jcraft.jsch.jce.*
-keep class com.jcraft.jzlib.ZStream
-keep class com.jcraft.jsch.Compression
-keep class org.ietf.jgss.*
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn com.jcraft.jsch.**

-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses

-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-dontwarn kotlin.Unit   

-dontwarn afu.org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn org.checkerframework.**
-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
```

I assumed that the problem is coming from Proguard, because i can normally generate an APK without it.
I've also tried to add different 'com.android.support:support-annotations:xx'  implementations before syncing project but the problem persists.

The project is imported from a git repo.

Comment: Please post your main gradle file.

Comment: I added some more details in the Gradle file.

Comment: This is app level gradle. There is one more build.gradle listed under main module.

Comment: Actually, they were 2 more build.gradle files, i edited the post correspondingly.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The problem is solved! I needed to add

`implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'` under

dependencies in `android/app/build.gradle`
in my library. The message warning was enough explicit to do that, but I didn't think about modifying the library dependencies.

Comment: I also had to update my supportLibVersion in top-level gradle.build to: `supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"`

Comment: Please edit the answer to explain which files this goes in

Comment: yes it worked add it under dependencies in ```android/app/build.gradle```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was adding a configuration to resolve this conflict by forcing the system to use the specified dependency path despite having many other options.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
      cacheDynamicVersionsFor(0, 'seconds')
      cacheChangingModulesFor(0, 'seconds')

      force('com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0')
  }
  transitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error message and resolved it by removing this line:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

in your project level gradle.

Comment: it didn't work :( Can you explain at least why it had to fix this issue?

Comment: I think `jcenter()` is better